# Py.Test add marker to all tests

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-asyncio

I am using python asyncio with pytest-aysncio, which means all my tests look like:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_my_func():
    result = await my_func()
    assert result == expected
```

Which works great, but I would prefer to not have to decorate every single function in order to get them to work. Is there a way in pytest to add this marker to every test function?

Comment: Use pytest-aiohttp, man!

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov that doesnt seem to work, `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could add a [`pytest_collection_modifyitems`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) hook to your `conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    for item in items:
        item.add_marker('asyncio')
```

Or to do so filewise, you can set `pytestmark = pytest.mark.asyncio` globally in that file.

Comment: Note that this will emit a warning that `asyncio` is an unknown marker. There's a few ways to declare marks; like the `pytest.ini` file, but also by calling [`config.addinivalue_line`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/markers.html#custom-marker-and-command-line-option-to-control-test-runs) in plugins

Comment: @kelloti There's no need to do that, because the `pytest-asyncio` plugin [already does so](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/blob/v0.18.1/pytest_asyncio/plugin.py#L184-L189).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `pytest-asyncio>=0.17`, you can put the following into your `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
asyncio_mode=auto
```

This removes the need to mark each test; just declaring the test function with `async def` is sufficient.